# creating an alias in ubuntu , in .profile

Tags: linux, alias, .profile

I can't figure out why this simple alias isn't work. I've read online an example on creating  it and don't know where I'm going wrong...

I've added the following to my `.profile` file at the bottom:

`alias profile='sudo nano ~/.profile'`

When I type in 'profile' in the terminal it says command not found...

I have a feeling this is a very very simple error I'm making.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you log out and back in?

Alternatively you could just type

```
source .profile
```

and that should activate your alias. Many people using `bash` set their aliases up in the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Thank you! This worked....so what does this do? I did first try entering it there, but when that didn't work went to .profile (as I remember doing in the past)

Comment: When you log in, a number of configuration files (usually they are "hidden files", ie. start with a `.` in the file name) get read and "executed"/processed. When you logged out and back in, your `.profile` was processed and the alias was set up. `source .profile` does this "manually" without you having to log out and back in.

Comment: do you know why i would need to do the source command each time I open a terminal window? It seems to not remember it. Thanks!

Comment: @iight You should not have to do that. I would suggest you move your aliases to the `.bashrc` file. That way each time you opened a console  it would be active. Some config files get processed only when you log in first, others each time you open a console, you'd have to read up on that, but I'm pretty sure that `.bashrc` will work for you.

Comment: Yes all is well now! Thanks for your help today Levon!

Comment: @iight Happy to been able to help.

Comment: I tried adding an alias to my .profile and it doesn't create it once I log out and back in. I've read multiple places it should work putting it in the ~/(username)/.profile but it doesn't work for me.

When I added it to a .bashrc file in the same location, then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

to add alias permanent you can edit `~/.bashr`c and add alias to it

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

add alias at the end

```
alias update_linux='sudo apt-get update'
```

dont forget to refresh bashrc configuration.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

for more details on creating alias you can read following blog: [Codebucket](http://codebucket.co.in/create-an-alias-for-terminal-commands-linux/)

Comment: Thanks @Arvind ! I've since figured this out, but I never knew about the `source ~/.bashrc` , I always reset my connection. Thanks!