# replace java -jar by a bash command line

Tags: java, bash, binary, alias

It's boring to run java commande using java -jar arg1 arg2 .. 
Is there a way to create a standard command line easily from a script file, without alias ?
For instance using /usr/bin/trimmomatic to replace

```
java -jar /PROGS/EXTERN/trimmomatic-0.35.jar MYFILE
```

by

```
trimmomatic MYFILE
```

Comment: Please see what does an `alias` does in `bash` http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Comment: There are multiple answers on SO for similar questions, like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397508/creating-an-alias-in-ubuntu-in-profile and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647744/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias-for-ubuntu

Comment: I wasn't clear sorry. I m asking if it's possible to do this using a bash script file. For instance /usr/bin/trimmomatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias trimmomatic='java -jar /PROGS/EXTERN/trimmomatic-0.35.jar'
```

Then restart your shell (or do `source ~/.bashrc` if you don't want to restart it) and the alias should be available.

Alternatively, you can define a bash function (e.g. in your `~/.bashrc` again):

```
trimmomatic() { java -jar /PROGS/EXTERN/trimmomatic-0.35.jar "$@"; }
```

or a wrapper shell script that you can put in you $PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /PROGS/EXTERN/trimmomatic-0.35.jar "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks I know about alias. I was thinking about a file into the bin folder PATH.

Comment: That won't work, `$PATH` is only for native executables/scripts, not for `jar` files.

Comment: @dridk See my updated answer for the other alternatives.

Comment: yes, but it's possible to run Python script . Why the shebang #!/bin/java -jar doesn't exist ?

Comment: @dridk The shebang must be part of the file to be executed (the jar file in this case). If jar files did start with the string `#!/bin/java -jar\n`, then you would just `chmod +x` and execute like you do with standard executables. Unfortunately for you, this is not the case, so you cannot do that.